# How to run drill in non installed system with jar file?

Tags: hadoop, jar, apache-drill

I'm making the program using Apache drill 1.8.

I'm trying to run this program in non-drill installed HDFS.

The way I think is using jar file, drill contained jar file can run this program because it is running in virtual machine.

But I'm not confident this way. Can it work?

If this way works, How to contain drill in jar file?

If not, what kind of way?

Plus question, how to change storage configuration using Java code?

Comment: How are using accessing drill - JDBC, REST or any other way?

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter drill or hdfs running on the same machine or not.

Why do you need to create a jar.

If you are using Maven as building tool, add Drill JDBC driver dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.drill.exec</groupId>
    <artifactId>drill-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Sample code:

```
public class TestJDBC {

    // Host name of machine on which drill is running 
    public static final String DRILL_JDBC_LOCAL_URI = "jdbc:drill:drillbit=192.xxx.xxx.xxx";

    public static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        try {
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ce) {
            ce.printStackTrace();
        }

        try (Connection conn = new Driver().connect(DRILL_JDBC_LOCAL_URI, null);
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();) {

            String sql = "select employee_id,first_name,last_name from cp.`employee.json` limit 10";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.print(rs.getInt("employee_id") + "\t");
                System.out.print(rs.getString("first_name") + "\t");
                System.out.print(rs.getString("last_name") + "\t");
                System.out.println();
            }
            rs.close();

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```